# How can I track resource usage on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, memory, logging, cpu-usage

I am looking for a way to log system resource usage (Memory, CPU, Disk IO, Network IO, Swap Usage, etc...) on a Mac. Most of the tools I have seen (Activity Monitor, top, and 3rd party tools) only display the current usage for these metrics. I am hoping to be able to gather this data so that I can have a full set of diagnostic information in order to be able analyze reported issues.

I know this question is similar to [How can I track and log CPU and memory usage on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/581108/how-can-i-track-and-log-cpu-and-memory-usage-on-a-mac/849871#849871), but I am looking for a way that can get the full picture of resource usage, not just CPU and memory. I know on linux systems, there are tools like atop and sar. Atop does not seem to be available for Macs and there does not seem to be a way to get sar to do this sort of continuous logging without some significant hacks (see [Mac osx sar Hack - blog post)](http://www.andreaswacker.com/blog/2005/11/19/sar-under-os-x-1043/). I know this blog post is dated, but I have not seen anything newer.

Ideally, I would like to be able to have a log of the resource utilization of a mac over the past 24 hours. I would greatly appreciate advice on how I may be able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use `telegraf` for system resource usage collection on a CentOS server, and it works pretty well. You can store the metrics to file or a database (`influxdb`, for example) or any other supported ways. You can also visualize the metrics through `grafana`. The three softwares mentioned are all open source. They should work on mac.

Comment: I can verify that these do work on macs. It is actually pretty sophisticated. In your experience, how stable is this solution?

Comment: @Andrew This solution should be stable enough for server metric collection. Might be overkill for one Mac.