# Does macOS record the RAM usage log?

Tags: macos, command-line, memory

Basically as title. More specifically,

1. I want to know whether the RAM usage logs of my MacBook, since I first bought it, are recorded or not.
2. If it did get recorded, which terminal command/tool(s) should I use to see it? More specifically I would like to know the peak usage of RAM of all time.

Comment: You can track it manually - see https://superuser.com/questions/581108/how-can-i-track-and-log-cpu-and-memory-usage-on-a-mac - but afaik its is not logged historically by default. If it were, it would ordinarily be cycled with the other logs, so best you'd get would be the past month.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thanks for the info!

Comment: activity monitor should do this no?

Comment: @Mastaxx: but where to find the highest usage in history?